# how to import a library and use a class within that library in eclipse

Tags: java, import

I am a begginer in Java and I am currently importing a library which provides me with a deepClone() method. The aforementioned library uses a class named **Cloner**. After importing the library via ->Properties-> Java Build Path -> Add External Jar -> selecting the zip file, I try to use that class but everytime I try to create a **Cloner** object a warning message appears *cloner cannot be resolved to a type*.

I might need to import the class but as it's my first time doing this I can't really tell, I looked it up but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

Feel free to ask for a screenshot or anything that you need in order to solve this headcracker!

Comment: Selecting the zip file? I usually select the .jar file. Then importing the library can be done with a mouseover of the object, and selecting the appropriate import library, or ALT+SHIFT+O.

Comment: I used the file downloaded from this link, after I unziped it I couldn't find the .jar file so I just went with the ZIP and eclipse didn't give me any trouble. Is it possible to do it this way? https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning

Comment: You need to import that class:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: I see, how can I know the full name that I need to type in order to import it correctly? (Thx for the help, I know I'm a noobie)

Comment: Hey, sorry it took a while, but here's what I would do: Clone the project and run a maven build. This will get you your jar file. Include that jar in your current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This zip file is just a sources which you shoud compile by youself, but you can download jar file and import it from [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.com.robust-it/cloning). Direct link for latest version (17 May 2016) [direct link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/uk/com/robust-it/cloning/1.9.2/cloning-1.9.2.jar)

In pom.xml you can see groupId and artifactId so you can find artifact in maven repo in the future